# How do I efficiently get n most frequent elements from my collection?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am trying to do something like this:

```
List("c","a","b","b","a","a").groupBy(identity).toList.sortBy(_._2.size).reverse.take(2).map(_._1)
```

This produces the result I need, the list of two most frequent occurrences:

```
 List("a", "b")
```

Only this is inefficient, in that `groupBy` creates a bunch of collections which I don't need; a simple count would have sufficed.

What's the idiomatic way to do this?

Imagine that the original list is very long, while the number of distinct values is small.

Answer (score 0):

The most trivial solution is iterating over the list and counting the frequency of the strings.

Implementation with the functional approach (using foldLeft over collection):

```
 object Main extends App {

   val strings: List[String] = List("c", "a", "b", "b", "a", "a")

   val counts: Map[String, Int] = strings.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Int]) { (map, string) =>
     val count: Int = map.getOrElse(string, 0)  //get the current count of the string
     map.updated(string, count + 1)  //update the map by incrementing string's counter
   }

   println(s"counts = $counts")

 }
```

By this implementation, you are both avoiding intermediate collections and achieve `O(n)` time.

From this point you can use `counts` for your aims. If you want to get the most frequent words for example:

```
 val sortedFrequency: Vector[(String, Int)] = counts.toVector.sortWith(_._2 > _._2)
 println(s"sorted frequency${sortedFrequency}")
```

Since we are assuming the resulting `counts` map is small in size, the operations like sorting over that collection can be ignored.

Comment: `sortWith(_._2 > _._2)` will avoid the reversal, and `toVector` might be slightly more performant.

Comment: it actually creates N intermediate maps. No improvement over `groupBy`

Comment: @Dima, I'd hope the N intermediate maps had a lot of structural sharing, though so shouldn't be too bad (a mutable map might be better still, not benchmarked it though). And it doesn't create lists of each duplicated item only to take the length of them, so it beats `groupBy`.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Well, elements are inserted by reference, so, I doubt, that keeping around references to N elements is significantly more expensive than a Map with N integers. The intermediate maps do have some structural sharing, but creating them (in the default implementation) involves copying the entire trie. 
I am not saying this is terribly expensive, just that it isn't any cheaper than `groupBy`. 
If the input source is really-really huge (and I mean really!), then a mutable map (or better yet, a priority queue!) would give some performance improvement, otherwise, don't bother.

Comment: My benchmark (with 10000 random ints under 25 as strings) shows that `.groupBy` solution is about 3 times FASTER than `foldLeft`. What would be better than `.groupBy`. `foldLeft` with mutable map is only marginally faster than than with immutable (still, roughly, 3 times slower than `groupBy`)

Comment: Interesting. Looking at the source for `groupBy` https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.3/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableLike.scala#L1 it would be interesting to try that with a Map of counts rather then elements. It seems it's the `for` vs `foldLeft` that determines the efficiency

Comment: Ok, I don't know what's going on here, but this: 
`def counts[T](l: Seq[T]) { val m = mutable.Map.empty[T, Int].withDefault(_ => 0); for(x <- l) m(x) += 1; m }` is about as fast as `foldLeft` with mutable map, and still three times slower than `.groupBy`

Comment: Here is my benchmark code: https://gist.github.com/dimatkach/4a619664b894d5cd7a36aa025f530996
(the mutable solutions are actually better than 3-times slower, and improving with the growing number of unique keys, but still slower than groupBy)

Comment: I don't understand why that would be slower, since it's the same structure as the `groupBy` only doing less in each iteration. Very odd.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comments to the other answer, a `foldLeft` solution is actually inferior to your original `.groupBy`.

Note, that you seem to be optimizing the wrong thing here to begin with: counting duplicates is `O(N)` either way, while sorting them to find the most frequent ones is `O(N*log(N))`, so it is likely to be the dominating factor in the performance of your implementation.

You can avoid having to sort your counts, by simply keeping around a small array or a tuple with the two largest so far, and updating it as you go with a a single linear scan.

```
grouped
  .mapValues(_.size)
  .foldLeft(("", Int.MinValue) -> ("", Int.MinValue)) {
     case (((a, x), (b,y)), (_, cnt)) if cnt < x => (a,x) -> (b,y)
     case ((_, (b,y)), (str, cnt)) if cnt < y => (str, cnt) -> (b, y)
     case ((_, keep), (str, cnt)) => keep -> (str, cnt)
  }
```

Here is a fancier implementation of the same idea, using a bounded `PriorityQueue`: https://gist.github.com/ryanlecompte/5746241

Comment: "optimizing the wrong thing". .Not really. From the OP: "number of distinct values is small". The N in counting duplicates is not the same N as in the sort. However, Wikipedia covers the "top M" issue comprehensively here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm

Comment: As long as it's greater than 5 ... Ok, let's say, greater than 100. If it's smaller than that, it doesn't matter in any way whatsoever how you select them. Could bubble sort without noticing any difference :)

Comment: Selection isn't quite the same task BTW. It is about finding K-th smallest, not finding K smallest.

Comment: It's  pretty much the same in practice. You can't really tell which is the k-th smallest without having an idea of what the smallest to k-1th smallest is :)